# how to delete Elastic Beanstalk app while keeping the amazon RDS database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk app and an amazon RDS database associated with it. But now, I want to delete my app from Elastic Beanstalk while keeping the database as exactly it is. As far as I read in documentation when you terminate your app in the elastic beanstalk other associated resources will also be terminated. So is there a way to delete my app from elastic beanstalk while keeping the database? Thanks!

Comment: Can you not simply clone the DB before terminating the environment? Elastic Beanstalk is a configuration pulling different AWS resources together. When you delete the configuration, you will be deleting everything defined by the configuration.

Comment: Yeap I can, that is what I will do I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc has the answer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.terminating.html

> If you have data from an environment that you want to preserve, create
>   a snapshot of your current database instance before you terminate the
>   environment. You can use it later as the basis for new DB instance
>   when you create a new environment. For more information, see [Creating](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html)
>   a DB Snapshot in the Amazon Relational Database Service [User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html).

Answer (score 0):

AWS enables you to set the RDS created from Beanstalk to be retained on Beanstalk deletion. To update this setting, go to your **Beanstalk -> Networking and database -> Database deletion policy** and select **Retain**